# Importing ActiveX components developed with C# into Delphi 2011?

Tags: c#, delphi

Can be imported components builders as ActiveX with C# into Delphi ?

Comment: If it's a true ActiveX then I see no reason why you could not do this. I've never done it myself though!

Comment: i dont know what is true ActiveX ... just wonering if it's worth to continue researches further, or stop and look about another solution.

Comment: I didn't know you could produce and export native ActiveX COM dual interfaces with C# apps. Apparently you can: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zsfww439(vs.71).aspx

Comment: A better solution than activeX would be the RemObjects hydra technology which offers a very high-quality way to use .Net assemblies inside delphi applications.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to MSDN sources, using C# it is possible to produce a valid ActiveX control, and I have found several tutorials that claim to be showing writing a C# ActiveX control.

I would expect that such a control would easily be imported into Delphi, but as I lack a sample control, and have never tried it, I can only give you a "it looks possible".